# Erro ao criar uma Controller na API com Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Boa noite estou tentando criar uma Controller em uma Api com Entity Framework, associei ela a o projeto, configurei as injeções de dependência, mas quando vou criar uma Controller ele retorna o erro:
[image: Erro ao adicionar uma controller]

Tentei muita coisa e até daqui e nada, se alguém puder ajudar fico grato.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, não achei uma solução em criar a controller com Entity Framework, a solução foi criar uma sem o Entity e fazr os métodos na mão mesmo, bom que aprende.